# How to produce a effect like this? Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

How to produce a effect like this? Adobe Illustrator.

[image: How to produce a effect like this? Adobe Illustrator.]

Comment: This is *not* a "tutorial on demand" web site. Please share what you have tried and where that may be failing. And please only use *relevant* tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called Truchet pattern and can easily be created by using script. Script follows as and rest follow gif tutorial attached. Every time you use this script, effect will be random:

```
object = app.activeDocument.selection [0] ;

for(j=0; j<40; j++)
{
//make a row
for(i=0; i<40; i++)
  {
    newobject = object.duplicate() ;
    newobject.translate(object.width*(i+1),-object.height*(j+1)) ;
    newobject.rotate(Math.floor(Math.random()*4)*90) ;
  }
}
```

[image: written truchet script for adobe illustrator_01]

[image: written truchet script for adobe illustrator_02]

[image: written truchet script for adobe illustrator_03]

[image: written truchet script for adobe illustrator_04]

Comment: Thanks, what a simple solution.

Comment: @coreladvanced You are more than welcome.

Comment: If you put four spaces before your code it formats it as a code block. (Or select code and press code button in editir to add four spaces). Plese dont bold big blocks of code. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @joojaa It was copy/paste problem and I did not notice. Thanks for correction though.

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: @Scott, What extension I should choose to save the script in "Notepad++" after pasting, so then import it into AI? Thanks for the cool script!

Comment: @Masoud Moghaddam You can save as js (extension) in notepad.